# Playing a film with subtitles from .srt

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I have a film on DVD, and a suitable .srt file. How do I convert this into a functioning stream ? I am using Windows 10 and have tried using VLC (latest version, downloaded today) to do this but I can read the plaintext of the .srt and most of the entries there are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably not encoded correctly. You might need to open them in your textviewer and do a save as to your local encoding. Try to save it as UTF-8 or WIN-xxxxx. There are a few options. The SRT has to have the same name of the film of the DVD(data) and be the same directory as the file on the DVD(data) to be load automatically on startup by most players. If the film is the DVD-VIDEO format, then you need to re-encode the movie with the subtitles embedded into it and burn it back on to a blank DVD.